# Azure Storage - allow to upload, but deny to update

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to have ability to upload/delete a blob to Azure storage, but deny to update (modify) blob. I see only 3 types of access - Private, Blob, Container. But none from them does not allow to upload and deny to update.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure Storage this can be done creating the policies on containers and blobs. checkout this msdn blog 
**https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/ 

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2/**